# My RapidEye image won't appear in GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, satellite

I have several RapidEye images that I want to use for object segmentation in GRASS GIS. When I import the the bands they all look like this and the same goes with a RGB composite:
[image]

I've used these images in ArcGIS and SAGA GIS before but never experienced this. The images are in tif. Any suggestions as to what the problem may be?

Comment: Hello and welcome to GIS.SE. It may help us if you can tell us what file format your images are in before importing them to GRASS

Comment: yes sorry, that should have been mentioned. Tif format.

Comment: Do you know if the TIFF files have been compressed?

Comment: Not that I know of, they might have. I got them on a external hard drive from a public institution. I have had problem with those images in SAGA gis but those were different kind of problems.

Comment: Did you try setting a color ramp? What is the problem with the image above?

Comment: Yeah, ok . So i set the color table to grey and got a nice black and white picture. But how do i get the RGB picture to actually display natural color. The problem with the picture above is that I want it to show natural colors.

Answer (score 3):

You need to assign a grey color table (r.colors).

To get an RGB composite run d.rgb (composite on the fly) or r.composite (saved as new map) or via graphical user interface (on the fly).

And with i.landsat.rgb (called now i.colors.enhance in GRASS GIS 7) you can color-balance the natural colors.

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work for the images. After having changed the the images from 32 bits to 16 bits Grass handles them better and for some reason I could create a color image using run d.rgb.

Comment: GRASS can handle also 32 bit, no problem. Please explain " that didn't work for the images"...

Comment: The first time I tried to make a rgb composite the results were as green as the picture above. I'm new to grass (I'm experienced with ArcGIS and a got some experience with SAGA GIS) and I figured maybe there was some final tuning that I had not figured out yet. After converting the images into 16 bit, everything works, I've got no explanation other than I probably did something wrong the first time around with the full 32 (though I tried 3 or4 images, all green)  Thanks for the suggestions everyone.